# Vim mapping: Copy whole line X lines up/down and paste it X lines down/up

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, cut-copy-paste

I find myself doing the following very often: `xkyyxjp` (where x is a number).

I copy a whole line x lines up, and then I paste it x lines down (and vice versa); and so I wanted to make a map so I can do it automatically, ideally with: `x<Leader>u`, where x is the number and u is the letter that indicates the mapping. I tried:

```
nnoremap <Leader>u @='jyy'<CR>
```

and

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>u v:count1 kyy v:count1 jp
```

How could I write said mapping? Is there an already built-in key that does this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:copy` or a shortcut `:t` command for that:

```
:10t20
```

it will copy line 10 below line 20.

Or copy 10 previous lines below line 20:

```
:-10,t20
```

Instead of copying text directly to the buffer you can use `:yank` or `:y` command instead to yank lines:

```
:-10,y
```

and then paste with `p`. This you can map as:

```
nnoremap <space>u <cmd>exe "-" .. (v:count1 - 1) .. ",y"<CR>
```

Where `:exe` executes a "string" you can construct with string concatenation `..`. And `<cmd>expression<cr>` is the way to execute a command without changing modes.

If you want to yank a single line located before cursor then `:-10y` should do it, and a mapping:

```
nnoremap <space>u <cmd>exe "-" .. v:count1 .. "y"<cr>
```

Comment: Hi maxim,  thanks for the reply. The thing is (maybe I am misinterpreting this), but  I belive that mapping copies a whole bunch of lines.
Where instead, I just want to copy a **single** line that is x lines up, and paste it x lines down.
Is there a way to do that instead?

Comment: @PeterPetigru it should be easier then, `:-10y`